# Responsive image slider with multiple text elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Can you recommend me a free image slider that can have multiple text elements in a slide, and is responsive?

Also how do you deal with 1920x1080 image looking long and thin on mobile after scaling?

Comment: Seeking recommendations for off-site resources on SO is off-topic. As for your second question: Use a percentage width or height, not both. As long as you only set one of them, the other will adept.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find a slider you like here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/
But than you need to add bootstrap to the project see here: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/